# Where should I ask this question related to biochemistry?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I read that banana contains Potassium-40 isotope. But most common isotope is K-39.  K-40 makes up 0.012% (120 ppm) of the total amount of potassium found in nature. I need to ask why banana contains majority of that *rare* isotope instead K-39. And also I need to ask how chemistry works inside banana to capture only that isotope.

Where should I ask that question?

Both [Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry) and [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry) have a [biochemistry] tag.

Answer (score 5):

Tough question; good that you already realized there are two possible sites for this. When in doubt, it's best to rely on site experts, which are found on the sites' own Metas: [Biology Meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/) and [Chemistry Meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/). It could be that your question needs to be split up into one focused on biology and another one on chemistry.

I did found this question on Biology Stack Exchange: [Why do animals have more heavy nitrogen and carbon than plants?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43954/15950) which is also about isotope frequency in organisms.

Comment: Thank you. Say I need to ask "Why banana capture more K-40 and what mechanisms they use to identify that specific isotope?" along with "How banana extract that much of K-40 while it composes only 0.012% and make hundreds of tons of banana?"  I know these questions are related to biology, but I need chemistry behind it also need to be properly explained.

Comment: Perhaps. We're not biology or chemistry experts (well, some of us are), that's why I advice to ask on the sites' own metas.

Comment: Side question, does SO allow to repost that question on other meta sites? does it count as duplicate?

Comment: Cross-posting the same question is frowned upon indeed, but that pertains to main sites. And you're not asking exactly the same question; one could be 'What parts of this question can I ask on Biology.SE, and which parts are better off on Chemistry.SE" and vice versa.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking the question from a biological context (why does a banana...? how does a banana...?), so that'd belong on Biology.SE. As Glorfindel said, cross-posting is expressly forbidden. However, some overlap between site scopes is inevitable and natural, and in those cases, it's up to you as the asker which site you'd prefer to ask on. If you want answers from biologists, ask on Biology.SE. @Salitha

Answer (score 4):

This is either a Biology or a Physics question, but you have to know the answer to decide which one it really is. The problem is that your question is based on a false premise, bananas don't contain more of the rare, radioactive isotope relative to the common one, they simply contain more potassium entirely.

In general Biology would still be the most reasonable place for a question like this, if more detailed chemical or physical explanations are necessary to explain biological concepts they are entirely on-topic there.

Comment: Definitely a false premise, so it is unclear that it would be welcomed on either stack.

Comment: Questions with false premises are perfectly welcome: answers can just point out the falsity of the premises. That's very useful to others who may also be suffering under those same mistaken assumptions.